# FieldValue is not returning

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Sub GetData(ByVal SelectedColumn As String, ByVal Table As String, ByVal ConditionField As String, ByVal ConditionValue As String, ByVal FieldValue As Integer) 
    con.Close() 
    con.Open() Query = "select " & SelectedColumn & " from " & Table & " where " & ConditionField & " = " & ConditionValue 
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, con) 
    DR = cmd.ExecuteReader 
    While DR.Read 
        FieldValue = DR.Item(SelectedColumn) 
    End While 
    con.Close() 
End Sub
```

I create this sub to get one value to the database my database is Access 2010. When I run it the FieldValue is not returning the right value

```
Dim S As Integer 
GetData("Price", "ProductList", "ProductName", "'7up'", S) 
MsgBox(S)
```

Now I use the Sub and print the value that it get, but the MsgBox value is zero(0). it should be Eight(8). I try to put a msgBox in Sub and Print FieldVAlue after it gets the value and it printing the correct value. But why my dim "S" is still zero? By the way the Sub is in my Module

Comment: Post your code here, as text, please

Comment: Sub GetData(ByVal SelectedColumn As String, ByVal Table As String, ByVal ConditionField As String, ByVal ConditionValue As String, ByVal FieldValue As Integer)

        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        Query = "select " & SelectedColumn & " from " & Table & " where " & ConditionField & " = " & ConditionValue
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(Query, con)
        DR = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While DR.Read
            FieldValue = DR.Item(SelectedColumn)
        End While
        con.Close()

    End Sub

Comment: Dim S As Integer
        GetData("Price", "ProductList", "ProductName", "'7up'", S)
        MsgBox(S)

Comment: sorry i cant edit it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `FieldValue` is a copy of `S`. You really not setting `S` at all. Declare `ByRef FieldValue...` and you in business

In vb.net there are value and reference types. Value type parameters, such as `integer` are passed as copy of value. While reference types passing copy of address. When you passed int (10) `ByVal`, you passed copy. When you do `FieldValue = DR.Item(SelectedColumn)`, you set value inside your method. But you are not setting `S`. But if you pass it `ByRef`, you pass copy of address and in this case you set same value as `S`.

Of course, if you use `while` on the query that may return more then 1 result - it is a problem. At least, use `if` if you expect 1 value, or better yet - `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: thanks its working now :) but can you explain it to me?

Comment: @ArnoldBarrozo Please accept and upvote the answer then. I will add explanation to the answer

Comment: i see new lesson in VB. thanks a lot. last question you right in the While code but what should i replace in the While condition loop?

Comment: @ArnoldBarrozo If you expect single value - use instead of `ExecuteReader` use `ExecuteScalar`: `dim i as Integer? = cmd.ExecuteScalar().... if i.HasValue Then...` Or  use `Convert` - `dim i as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())`, in this case if no record found, you get `nothing` and convert will return `0`. Or if you use reader, instead of `while reader.read` do `IF reader.read`